# Exiv2: How to read photo with UTF8 filepath?

Tags: c++, exif, gtkmm, utf, exiv2

I am using GTKmm and exiv2 to read EXIF metadata form photos. However Exiv2 functions accept only std::string file paths... When I try it on not ASCII filepath it crushes the program.

Is there any way to read that data? It would be great if Exiv2 accepted Glib::ustrings...

I'm interested in solutions for Windows and Linux.

Comment: Please tag with appropriate OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have a solution!

You just need to use function **Glibmm::locale_from_utf8** to convert UTF8 string to std(ascii) string.
Here is an example:

```
void get_exif_data(const Glib::ustring &image_src)
{
        Exiv2::Image::AutoPtr image = Exiv2::ImageFactory::open(Glib::locale_from_utf8(image_src));
        image->readMetadata(); 
        Exiv2::ExifData &exifData = image->exifData();
        Exiv2::ExifData::const_iterator it = exifData.begin();
        for(it;it!=exifData.end();it++) cout << it->key() + ": " + it->getValue() << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is in Windows then you can use [`GetShortPathName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364989%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Note that this isn't guaranteed to work. Not all file systems support short path names, and on NTFS it's optional (i.e. can be turned off).